# PHP Mysql Select One Row but multiple result as it decrements

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I badly need a help

What I want is to Decrement Mysql Result

so if I have a Mysql Row like This

```
id = 1
task = task 1
burst time  = 4
```

I need to get multiple results decrementing burst time by two

```
id = 1
task = task 1
burst time  = 2

id = 1
task = task 1
burst time  = 2
```

need this for my round robin CPU scheduling algorithm

how can I do this? anyone please help

Comment: explain : `I need to get multiple results decrementing burst time by two`

Comment: well basically, this is a round robin CPU scheduling algorithm, I would like to query the current row and divide the burst time, into two or more